# Scp file from local to remote server with user password

Tags: scp

I'm trying to copy a file from my local machine macosx 10.11.6 to a remote server (digital ocean droplet) ubuntu 18.04 using scp.
I tried

```
scp -r /path/to/local/file username@ipaddress:/path/to/folder/where/to/copy
```

and I got permission denied.

I ssh into the server `cd /path/to/folder/where/to/copy` and test with touch `index.txt` and got permission denied.

I tried to touch `index.txt` with `sudo` which worked after input the password.

I tried install and use sshpas

```
sshpass -p 'mypassword' scp -r /path/to/local/file username@ipaddress:/path/to/folder/where/to/copy
```

And I got permission denied again.

What is the correct way to copy that file from local to the remote server passing the user password?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact error which scp is printing. Don't paraphrase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned here [SSH SCP Local file to Remote in Terminal Mac Os X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822192/ssh-scp-local-file-to-remote-in-terminal-mac-os-x?rq=1) , I had to do it in two times.
scp -r /path/to/local/file username@ipAddress:/home/username
then 
ssh username@ipAddress
sudo mv file path/to/destination/folder

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your remote server user doesn't have write permissions to your destination directory, that's why the touch fails.

You can either copy the file to somewhere else (your user's home?) or modify the destination folder's permissions with sudo and chmod to allow your user to write to the destination directory.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Lucas Lavandeira, I did ls -ld <directoryIWantToCopyTo> and got lrwxrwxrwx so it seems that I have the necessary permissions If i'm not mistaking.